# C++: Getting registry value only gives first character

Tags: c++, string, windows, winapi, registry

I'm trying to get a string value from the registry, but I'm only getting the first letter.

```
HKEY hKey;
char gamePath[MAX_PATH];
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,L"Software\\Blizzard Entertainment\\Warcraft III",0,KEY_READ,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
   DWORD type=REG_SZ, size=MAX_PATH;
   int error = RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"GamePath",NULL,&type,(LPBYTE)&gamePath,&size);
   if(error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
       cout << "Failed to read registry value: " << error << endl;

   RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
else cout << "Failed to read registry key." << endl;

cout << gamePath << endl; //output: C
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I just *have* to say that "ugly stuff like this is why I really *hate* writing Windows specific code". Gaah, the pain, it hurts.

Comment: Out of curiosity, gamepath[2] is what ? Any chance the encoding happens to be more than 8 bytes per char? (Not a Windows programmer)

Comment: It's a REG_SZ "string value". I'm new to this stuff so I don't know any more than that.

Comment: @bur please provide the output of 
for(int x = 0; x < MAX_PATH; x++){cout << gamepath[x];}

Comment: @jes: You *have* to write code like that, **every time** you access a C API. Of course, you have the option to use abstractions. C++ suits itself well to condense that code into a single line of code. Do you not understand abstractions, or C++, to understand, that this **isn't** specific to Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of `char` but `RegQueryValueEx` requires an array of `wchar_t` in a wide-character build. Most programs today will be wide-character applications, but you can use the Microsoft-defined constant `TCHAR` instead of `char` or `wchar_t` if you're unsure.

The reason you only get a single character is because the first character has a value between 1 and 255. The high byte of such a 16-bit character code is zero, so in memory it looks like a string terminator.

Comment: "*The hint is that you needed a type cast for that parameter, it shouldn't be necessary*" - actually it is, even if `gamePath` where declared as `wchar_t[]` instead. That parameter expects a `BYTE*` pointer, since `RegQueryValueEx()` can read binary data. The *real* hint is that *other* parameters are passing in `wchar_t` strings

Comment: @RemyLebeau good catch. I'm so used to seeing unnecessary casts as a red flag that I assumed this was another instance. I'll modify the answer.